# How to redirect to a route in SPA?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, authentication, redirect, identity

I have authentication done using external provider in Ids3.
After the user authenticates, my MVC home page is loaded, which bootstraps the angular app as such:

```
@section AppScripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Swagger")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/DevPortalApp")
}
```

When the user authenticates through one of the external providers, I am supposed to redirect to a specific page in angular:

```
https://myaddress/DevPortalApp/something
```

The problem is that with regular redirects I am stuck in the authentication loop. How can I redirect from my Home controller to a specific angular page?

```
 var externalLogin = accessToken.externalLogin;

 // Check if its from external
 if (externalLogin.Value != null)
 {
     var isValid = await externalLoginService.ValidateAccessToken(accessToken);
     RedirectToAction("~/#/myURLRedirect");
 }
```

Comment: Dont mess with routing to much... I recommend adding logic to the authentication part to check for authentication and redirect out if present or continue if missing. This is common for SPA authenticiation

Comment: Which is what I am trying to do but the redirect always ends up in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use angular router from [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki),
in shortly you can use `$state.go('your-new-view')`

In your app.js file create the states list-

```
$stateProvider
.state('someState', {
   url: '/someState',

   templateUrl: 'templates/Swagger.html',
   controller: 'Swagger'
})
```

And in your home controller you can just add redirect with `$state.go('someState')`

Comment: I've ended up doing exactly that and it worked. I assume there is no way for MVC controller to be aware of angular routing logic, and if my entire app is in "Home" view, I have no other choice but to use redirection on the client side. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are few multiple ways to integrate ASP.Net MVC Route with Angular Route.

I personally like [Miguel Castro's approach](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6BWiqmoiWls) which uses `*catchall` in ASP.Net MVC, and then pass it to Angular. Then let Angular handle at client-side.

You can fork my working sample code at [GitHub](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AngularAspNet).

**[MVC Route](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AngularAspNet/blob/master/src/Presentation/AngularAspNet.Web/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs)**

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Users",
   url: "users/{*catchall}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Users", action = "Index" });
```

**[Angular Route](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AngularAspNet/blob/master/src/Presentation/AngularAspNet.Web/App/Users/App.js)**

```
$routeProvider
   .when(rootPath + "users", {
      template: "<user-list></user-list>",
      caseInsensitiveMatch: true
   })
   .otherwise({ redirectTo: (rootPath + "users") });
```